# How do I prevent Vim from expanding ‘~’ during completion?

Tags: vim, tab-completion

I'm on my MacBook using Vim, and let's say for simplicity's sake that I have files `~/some_file.py`, `~/some_other_file.py`, and `~/user.py` open.  On macOS, `~` expands to `/Users/<username>`.

So if I type `:b user` in Vim command line and then hit tab to expand, it goes through each of the files instead of going straight to `~/user.py`.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem under linux (tildes are not resolved in my vim's completion list, so `:b home` gives me `~/home.py` before `~/some_file.py`), but...

Try typing `:b user` then complete with Shift+Tab. In that case, my vim (7.2.442 if that matters) completes with the last match, which is what you want.

Comment: You can't reproduce the problem because you probably open files in Vim right in the home directory.  Try this: `cd /tmp; vim ~/some_file.py ~/home.py`, and you'll likely have the problem.  At least I do in this case, so the behavior mentioned in the question is confirmed.

Comment: @ib, you're absolutely right. Completing with Shift+Tab still works, though.

Comment: Yes, I agree that `Shift+Tab` is the best life-hack in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change Vim built-in buffer completion. The only
thing I can suggest (besides opening these files already from the home
directory) is to define your own version of the `:b` command with
the desired completion. It could be something like this:

```
function! CustomBufferComplete(a, l, p)
    let buf_out = ''
    redir => buf_out
    silent buffers
    redir END

    let buf_list = map(split(buf_out, "\n"), 'substitute(v:val, ' .
    \   '''^.*"\%(\~[/\\]\)\?\([^"]\+\)".*$'', "\\1", "g")')
    return join(buf_list, "\n")
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=custom,CustomBufferComplete B b <args>
```

(Note that it cuts off the `~/` part of a path before returning
the completion list.)